# How to have a local only changeset in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, repository

Is there a way to have local only changesets? which means those changesets should never be sent to the remote repository. My scenario in more detail -

I want to make certain changes to configurations which make sense only on my local environment and not on the remote repository. I want to keep it in a local changeset, that should never get pushed to the remote repository. Right now i always have to either shelve / unshelve or redo these changes.

Comment: While not a direct solution, consider Queues for managing such changes.

Answer (score 5):

You can put your changeset in a `secret` phase, Mercurial won't bother you with it, and it will not get pushed. You may need a specific branch for this too, as all descendants will be secret as well.

However, what you are really looking for is the Mercurial Queues (mq extension), which allow you to apply and unapply patches on top of any changeset.